# Be able to send an email to an email address, and have that appear on a web page

Tags: java, email

I want to be able to send an email to an email address, and then have it appear on a web page. Is this possible?

My guess is you'd have to write your own email server, something which I am not capable of doing. So I am assuming this won't be possible for me.

But if there is some way it can be done, that would be great. I generally program in Java and use Tomcat as my app server.

Comment: So you'd like to generate an email, send it to some address and also display the generated text on a web page? Or should the web server be the email receiver and display the received message on the web page?

Comment: You want something as blogspot's publish-by-email? look at apache james - you have almost everything there http://james.apache.org/index.html

Comment: Well, you could send email to a gmail address, which can be read through a web interface, but do you expect the user to have the page open ,to check for updates?  That is something I do for gmail, but would be reluctant to do for 'some web-site'.  Why not simply send the user an email to whatever address they prefer?

Comment: Hmm.. 3 comments each with questions.  This has the smell of a poorly specified question.

Comment: @Andrew, the idea is that you can ask a question to many people and they all respond. Each response should be "repliable" through an email client. But if you want to see all responses and messages, there's a web page that can be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you wouldn't have to run your own SMTP server. You'd simply need to be able to retrieve mail from a POP3 or IMAP server, using something like the mail client API found in `javax.mail`.

It would be up to you to decide how much control you'd give to users. For example, who specifies the IMAP settings? Who decides which messages to fetch and display? Maybe that's all pre-configured. Maybe you write full-featured, web-based email client that can send messages as well as retrieve. This is all determined through the design of your web application.

Comment: Thanks erickson. I know this is not a very specific question, there's still a lot of thinking/reading todo . But that puts me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write your own mail server. You can use an ordinary (external) mail server and poll its inbox via POP3 or IMAP from your software. This introduces a short delay up to the full poll interval, but that might or might not be acceptable for you.

I can't give you a good tip for a email client lib to use for that, though.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) of sending email trough Google's SMTP server.